# NodeJS - How to connect to remote PC that runs Node app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo

I have a Nodejs client app, and a Nodejs server app. I use Apollo GraphQL for network.

These communicate fine if run on the same pc. They also work fine if the client is on another pc and server on my pc, over LAN only. They fail to communicate via internet.

My code that works right now:

server:

```
server.listen(PORT, '0.0.0.0',() ...
```

client:

```
 const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({

 uri: 'ws://192.168.10.41:8081/subscriptions',
```

Comment: If the problem is that you are behind a NAT router, you are looking for "NAT traversal".

Comment: @Bergi are you talking about the server or the client pc?

Comment: The server not being reachable from the internet

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all you must be sure that both nodes have a public IP, otherwise if you are behind a symmetric NAT you will not be able to do that.

After that you can use some of the modules of node, for example UDP(user datagram protocol) to try the connection.

Good Luck